# Data table Persistance

Tags: javascript

I need to trap the manual re-sizing of a column width in data table. Then store all the column widths into a cookie so that the next time the page is loaded the columns can be set according to the user preferences.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this jQuery library [carhartl/jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and easy to implement.

example :

```
$.cookie('width', '200'); // setting the cookie
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I am using more number of columns in a data table so how to store all column size width.                                                                                  Thanks

Comment: can you give example data you want to store?